# How to append row into a table without using the <tr> tag?

Tags: jquery, html-table, append, row

I know how to append a new row into a table using jquery. The simpliest way to do that is using tags `<tr>`:

```
function insertRow(data, reportNumber) {  
    var guid = $(data).find('ID').text();  
    var portId = $(data).find('PortID').text();  
    var status = $(data).find('Status').text();  
    $('#gvwCashRegisterList').append(  
            "<tr class=\"cashRegisterRow\"><td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + guid +   "\"/></td><td>" + new Date().toLocaleString() + "</td><td>" + guid + "</td>  <td></td><td>" + reportNumber + "</td><td>" + portId + "</td><td>" + status + "</td><td><a   href=\"CashRegisterList.aspx\">Select</a></td></tr>"  
        );  
}
```

Is there any known way to do that without using the tags `<tr>`? For example : jQuery functions, plugins or libraries?

Comment: not exact duplicate but might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: It is possible do that in Javascript, by using insertRow function :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the `<tr>` tag can generate a table row in HTML—there's no other way to replicate their behavior with another tag in a table.

There's a cleaner way to append table rows, though:

```
$("table tbody").append(
    $("<tr>") // create new tr element
        .attr("class","newTR") // set its class
        .append(
            $("<td>") // create a new td element within the tr
                .html("But this is new!") // set its content
        )
);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/Cek6e/).

Be very mindful of the lack of semicolons `;` (after the second `append()`, for example, and the `html()`).

Answer (score 2):

There's an even cleaner way using 1.4+ syntax:

```
$("table").append(
    // create new tr element
    $("<tr></tr>", {
        "class": "newClass", // set its class
        html: $("<td></td>", { // create a td element within the tr
          text: "Table cell" // add text content
        })
    });
});
```

Now everything is neatly encapsulated within the new tr object. Attributes and content are defined in the second argument (object literal) passed to the $() method ;)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do this:

```
$('<tr class="myclass" />')
    .append($('<td />').html('whatever here'))
    .appendTo('table');
```